# undefined method `within'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, geokit

I followed the installation procedure of geokit-rails3, here is my conf :

```
Using rails (3.0.4) 
Using activerecord (3.0.4) 
Using geokit (1.5.0) 
Using geokit-rails (1.1.4)
```

I get this error "undefined method `within' for #" when i try to query with the "within" method. (note that i am new to rails and maybe missing something obvious)

Here is my class definition :

```
class Snip < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    acts_as_mappable :default_units => :kms,
                   :default_formula => :sphere,
                   :distance_field_name => :distance,
                   :lat_column_name => :latitude,
                   :lng_column_name => :longitude
```

end

In my controller i have :

```
@userLocation = GeoKit::LatLng.new(params[:lat],params[:lng])
@snips  = Snip.within(params[:distance], :origin => @userLocation)
```

Here is what i added to my gemfile :

```
gem 'geokit', '>= 1.5.0'
gem 'geokit-rails', '1.1.4'
```

Do you have any idea why i get this error ?

Thanks in advance,
Vincent.

Answer (score 0):

Your gemfile asks for geokit-rails, that's the Rails 2 version. You need to replace that with geokit-rails3